# mod_rewrite redirection issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've looked through the related questions, but no luck.

I'm trying to rewrite something like this: http://www.example.com/v2/index.php/en/company/careers/training-and-implementation-specialist/

to this: http://www.example.com/en/company/careers/training-and-implementation-specialist/

To make things a little more confusing, The "**index.php**" in the URL above is a file, not a directory.  I'm trying to make a rule where www.example.com/v2/index.php/*(anything)* turns into www.example.com/*(anything)*

I feel like this should be easy, and I tried this: RewriteRule ^v2/index.php/(.*) /$1 [L]

but no luck -- it gets 404'd for anything I try that's in /v2/index.php.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you want to do, I believe you have it backwards. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v2/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `.` between index and php in `RewriteRule ^v2/index.php/(.*) /$1 [L]`

To rewrite try-`RewriteRule ^v2/index\.php/(.*)$ /$1 [L]`

if you want to redirect, change `[L]` to `[R,L]`